# Creating Android UI dynamically in java code

Tags: java, android-layout, android

The scenario is Activity A receives input from activity B after it exits, process the data and update layout C (with given ID, relativelayout) within activity A accordingly.

And this is my approach:

1. Within the triggered function, create a new RelativeLayout
2. Update the RelativeLayout with proper attributes, and add views (buttons and textviews) to it
3. Use findR.ID.layout_C_id to retrieve layout C
4. I'm stuck

Questions:

1. How do I continue from here?
2. RelativeLayout(Context context) is the constructor. What am I supposed to pass in?
3. I thought about using updateViewLayout(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params), but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Didn't get you. What exactly you are trying to update? Give us an example. By the way, you need to pass `this` (Activity context) in `RelativeLayout(Context context)`.

Comment: I was trying to update at least 2 layouts within an activity. For example, there are 3 layouts in the activity. After input is received and processed, layout 2 and 3 are hidden, certain attributes of layout 1 is updated, one of which is a button that will make layout 2 and 3 become visible again.

Comment: I don't think adding new view every time is optimal here. What you can do is hide layouts an button using `setVisibility()` and update the views in layout 1. e.g. for `textView.setText()` or `imageView.setImageResource()`.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I'm having in mind right now after reading the comment below. One last question is how am I supposed to set the ID for a drawable resources (a theme.xml in this case). My understanding is that I need the ID in order to pass in setBackgroundResource(resid)

Comment: Place the image in `drawable` folder under `res` folder with name `resid`. `ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId); imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.resid);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the basic point here :-( When you want to update an already-existing layout, you shouldn't inflate a new one. Instead, you fetch the views you want to update and put the data in them. Like this:

```
TextView t = myLayout.findViewById(R.id.someTextViewId);
t.setText(newlyObtainedData);
```

As for the Context, every activity inherits after it, so you can simply pass `this`.

Comment: Thank you. That makes much more sense to me now. No excuse but I literally just got introduced to android out of a hackathon so still taking baby steps.

Comment: No problem. Basically, in Android you operate on already-created views, obtained as above. It is a good idea to keep them as fields in the Activity, only invoking findViewById() in onCreate()